# Set up Landscape to run on Azure

Tags: cloud, landscape, azure

I have installed the latest Landscape Dedicated Server packages on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM on Azure and was successfully greeted by the initial setup. However, after entering name, e-mail, password, and clicking OK, it redirected me to app.storageacct.j10.internal.cloudapp.net/new-standalone-user instead of the next step. Is there a change I need to make in the Landscape config to get the redirect to function properly?

Answer (score 0):

If Deploying with the [bundle](https://jujucharms.com/u/landscape/landscape-scalable/8), you can do the following:

```
juju set apache2 servername=<hostname-you-want>
```

This should in turn set the root_url correctly in landscape (monitor `juju debug-log` after you do that to see the results).

If installing the landscape-server-quickstart package directly, it's a bit more involved, and will mean you need to visit the settings page on your account.  Try browswing to something like:

```
https://<server>/account/standalone/standalone-settings
```

directly and enter in the correct URL for your site.

Comment: Hi dpb, thanks for the feedback. I actually didn't do the charm install, I just added the ppa and installed the packages. I'll blow away the current VM, recreate, and install using juju.

Comment: @JoshuaBlair: It should still work with the package.  If you feel like going back and debugging, I'd be glad to help you look at it.  If you do, please post the logs in /var/log/landscape-server, specifically the appserver log would be good to see (like `cat /var/log/landscape-server/*appserver* | pastebinit`).

Comment: I actually didn't blow it away yet so I'll try the latter option you provided and see if that gets me anywhere.

Comment: Here's the pastebin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11102169/

Comment: Can you clear up a couple things for me -- 1) how does this hostname relate to what you initially access the page at? 2) What steps did you follow to install landscape originally?

Comment: 1) I did not know the long host name until after provisioning. It relates to it in the sense that how I access it currently is stf-landscape.cloudapp.net or landscape.seventwofive.com (CNAME to the cloudapp address). 2) I provisioned the Ubuntu 14.04 image on Azure, added the Landscape PPA, then installed the package.

Comment: @JoshuaBlair:  OK Thanks, some ideas:  1) Try accessing via the IP address directly.  2) Modify your /etc/hosts file adding the internal hostname of this instance "app.storageacct.j10.internal.cloudapp.net", tying that to the public ip address.  This should allow you to reach the next page.  Once inside landscape, you can change the "Root Url" under "LDS Settings" Right on the first page.

Comment: First, thank you for your willingness to help me troubleshoot this. I tried what you mentioned above and there was no difference and the errors appear to be the same. I also tried adding the instance hostname to my local hosts file (because I was unsure of which you were speaking) and went to a an "Unauthorized   A server error occurred page." I also don't want to waste too much of your time so I am going to try the juju route tomorrow as it seems like setting the root URL is the key to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set the hostname of the instance to something that you can resolve to from your laptop, before installing the landscape-server-quickstart package. The package uses whatever "hostname -f" returns as the root url, and that sticks for life.

What I do when I deploy to local containers, for example, which have the same problem, is to ssh in, set the right hostname in /etc/hostname and reboot it. Then I install the package.